# Set instances of a Form without the User input

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I am trying to set an instance of a Modelform that render through ListView.

Program Model:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id) + " - " + self.patient.username + " - " + self.program_name + " - " + str(self.date_posted)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('program-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Exercise Model:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    load_share = models.TextField(default="")
    breath_method = models.TextField(default="")
    recovery_method = models.TextField(default="")
    measure_method = models.TextField(default="")
    notes = models.TextField(default="")
    extra_info = models.TextField(default="")
    reps = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    sets = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.program_id) + " - " + str(self.pk) + " - " + " - " + self.name + " - " + str(self.date_posted)
```

Data Model:

```
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="0")
    set_number = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    spo2 = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    hr = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    physical_level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    breath_level = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    sys = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    dia = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    misc_input = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.exercise.name
```

My Exercise listView include the Data form that the User need to fill up, It is paginated to 1 exercise per page.
Exercise ListView:

```
# Exercise list inside each program + Data form
class ExerciseListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, ListView):
    model = Exercise
    context_object_name = 'exercises'
    form_class = DataForm
    paginate_by = 1

    def get_queryset(self):
        program_num = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Exercise.objects.filter(program=program_num)

    def form_valid(self, dataform):
        program_num = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(program=program_num)
        for exe in exercises:
            dataform.instance.exercise = exe.pk
            print(dataform.instance.exercise)
            return super(ExerciseListView, self).form_valid(dataform)


# Submit the Data form and redirect to the same page exercise
def add_data(request):
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    page = '?page={}'.format(page) if page else ''
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('program-detail', kwargs={'pk': data.exercise.program.pk}) + page)
```

forms.py:

```
class DataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = ['set_number', 'spo2', 'hr']
```

I didn't add all the fields because it is too long for test stage.

template.py:

```
{% extends "program/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <h3> Program Exercises List </h3>
    {% for exercise in exercises %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    {% if user.is_superuser %}
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'exercise-update' exercise.id %}">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" href="{% url 'exercise-delete' exercise.id %}">Delete</a>
                        <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.name }}</p>
                    {% else %}
                        <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.name }}</p>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.description }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.breath_method}}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.recovery_method }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.measure_method }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.load_share }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.notes }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.extra_info }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.reps }}</p>
                    <p class="article-content">{{ exercise.sets }}</p>
                </div>
                  <form action="{% url 'data-submit' %}{%if request.GET.page%}?page={{request.GET.page}}{%endif%}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Exercise Measurements</legend>
                            {{ form|crispy }}
                        </fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Save</button>
                        </div>
                  </form>
            </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
    {% if is_paginated %}

        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous Exercise</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next Exercise</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4" href="{% url 'web-home' %}">Exit</a>
        {% endif %}

    {% endif %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The instances I am trying to pass (in the Data form) without the user input are:

1. exercise - each Data form will be connect to an exercise in the database. as I mention before, the exercises are paginated 1 per page, maybe its something i can use?

I tried to solve it by that way:

```
    def form_valid(self, dataform):
        program_num = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        exercises = Exercise.objects.filter(program=program_num)
        for exe in exercises:
            dataform.instance.exercise = exe.pk
            print(dataform.instance.exercise)
            return super(ExerciseListView, self).form_valid(dataform)
```

It didn't work, I am still receiving id error for this instance.

2. set_number - each exercise as few sets. what I want to build is that:

the exercise as "sets" that define the number of sets the user need to perform. I want to set a "for" loop that count the number of sets and pass this instance "set_number" accordingly.

Each time the user submit the form, it will have an exercise and set_number.

Thanks!

Comment: you should include your DataForm code as well, since this is specifically an issue related to Form processing.

Comment: Ok, will edit now, although its just a simple meta class. Thanks.